# Undefined variable 'guild'

Tags: discord.py

I tried to make an addrole command but it is not working. I am taking the error: `undefined Variable 'guild' I made the code  abc=guild.roles()   for list the roles in the server but it is not working pls help

```
@client.command(pass_context=True) 
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role): 
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        xx=user.roles
        abc= guild.roles()
        if role in xx:
            if role in abc:
                 await user.add_roles(role)
                 await ctx.send(f'{user.mention}, {role} is given')
            else:
                 await ctx.send(f'The role you are looking for is not in the server')

        else:
             await ctx.send(f'The User already have the role')
    else:
         await ctx.send(f'You Have not enough permissions to run this command')
```

Answer (score 2):

`guild` currently doesn't exist in your scope. You'll need a `discord.Guild` object in order to get its roles.

By using `context`, you're able to get the guild that the command was sent from:

```py
@client.command() # context is automatically passed in rewrite
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role): 
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        xx = user.roles
        abc = ctx.guild.roles
        if role in xx:
            if role in abc: # see footnote
                 await user.add_roles(role)
                 await ctx.send(f'{user.mention}, {role} is given')
            else:
                 await ctx.send('The role you are looking for is not in the server')
        else:
             await ctx.send('The User already have the role')
    else:
         await ctx.send('You Have not enough permissions to run this command')

# irrelevent check, as if the user has it, then it's guaranteed to be in the guild.
# Also, if it didn't exist, the command would error
# because the role needs to exist in the guild (discord.Role in arg types)
# in order for the command to execute
```

I also removed the f-strings where they weren't necessary. They're used for formatting, hence the `f`, and in some places you weren't formatting variables inside the string, so I took them out.

Aside from that, your code is looking good so far, keep it up!

---

**References:**

- [f-string usage](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6.0+
- [Automatic context passing](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#context-changes)
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) - All of these attributes are available to you in a command's context. It's the first parameter, usually named `ctx`.
- [`Context.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild)
- [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles) - Notice that it's not a coroutine/function, so you don't need to call it with parentheses `()`. In the docs you'll see the parentheses on the end if it's a function, and a preceeding `await` if it's a coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to define guild as ctx.guild